# Get a single data from firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-reactive-forms

I want to get data from firebase by id and populate an update form. So first to get the id , I have the following but it returns all the id s as an array. How do I just get a single one after clicking on a list of data? After clicking the specific data, it takes me to the update form(reactive).As mentioned I want the update form to be populated by the id. The id is also passed to the link i.e client/id .
In service

```
getClient(id:any){
    return this.db 
    .collection('clients')
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(docData => {
      return docData.map(doc => {
        return {          
          id: doc.payload.doc.id                  
        };
      });
    }))
    .subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result);
       });
    
  }      
                                 }
```

This returns all the id in the firbase but **I want only the one clicked and populate the form accordingly.**

Comment: Just to clarify and be sure: the id you are passing to the getClient() method, is the one you want details on? Because if it is, you should just read the document, since you already have the ID

Comment: Yes, that the details I want with the ID passed in getClient() . I am new to this, so confused. Right now it is passing all the IDs but I need a single ID and also other data based on that particular ID to populate the form. I get following for 8 different data in the console log but need a single one.
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an ID, and you're passing it as argument to your getClient method, you can read the document directly. Your code should look like this:

```
getClient(id:any) {
    return this.db 
    .collection('clients')
    .doc(id)
    .get()
    .subscribe(doc => {
       console.log(doc.data());
    });
}
```

That's it. In your code, instead, you were listening for any changes that occur to your entire collection, not just the single document, and you were being notified everytime.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the ID in the component from the url with -   this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];    So in service I have the getClient , however it is not getting that id. So how do I get that id from url in the service?

Comment: That's a different issue from the original one. I suggest you to open a new question for that